# CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LogOnException

Tags: crystal-reports, report

When I move the code to the new server, I am getting error:

> Type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LogOnException' in
>   Assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' is not marked as
>   serializable.

It worked fine in my local. THe server is window 2008 R2, and the database is Oracle.

Comment: There are so many things that could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What is the datasource for your report?

As Ivan says, there are quite a few options- but you should probably start by checking you can connect from the new server. Are you using SSPI but not running the applications using a domain account with permissions etc